# Flutter search bar with Riverpod and changing suffixIcons

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Im making a Flutter app that shows a list of items, and I would like to filter this list based on a String in a search bar. I have Riverpod to provide a String that will be used in the filter. Base on this String I would like to change the `suffixIcon` when the String is not empty.

I only able to update only one or the other (text in search bar or the icon) together they don't work.

What is going on?

```dart
final searchProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');

class OverviewScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final houseDataValue = ref.watch(listHousesProvider);
    final searchController = TextEditingController();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.75.h, bottom: 1.5.h, right: 4.2.w, left: 4.2.w),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.darkGray,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.w, top: 0.4.h),
              child: TextField(
                controller: searchController,
                cursorColor: AppColors.medium,
                style: AppTypography.input,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search for a home',
                  hintStyle: AppTypography.hint,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: ref.watch(searchProvider).isNotEmpty // ICON DOES NOT UPDATE
                        ? Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined)
                        : Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  // OR THE TEXT INSIDE THE SEARCH BAR
                  ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).update((state) => state = value);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: and I also noticed an error in your `onChanged`. Please note how to correctly update the provider value in my answer.

Comment: I added a new snippet, could you take a look at it? I works like expected, but maybe could be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you need to make another provider that would only control the empty string. Try this:

```dart
final searchProvider = StateProvider<String>((_) => '');

final searchIsEmptyProvider = Provider<bool>(
    (ref) => ref.watch(searchProvider).isEmpty
);
```

Now your ui looks like this:

```dart
class OverviewScreen extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('$OverviewScreen been builded');

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search for a home',
            suffixIcon: Consumer(
              builder: (context, ref, _) => IconButton(
                icon: ref.watch(searchIsEmptyProvider) 
                    ? Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined)
                    : Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).update((_) => value);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I specifically used `Consumer` to show that only the icon will be rebuilt, and not the entire `OverviewScreen` widget.

---

Also note that you should create ANY controllers, text, focus, scroll, etc., only inside `initState`, and dispose of them inside `dispose`. This will help prevent memory leaks.

> Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare TextEditingController outside the build method. It's getting reassigned empty string on input changed.

```dart
class OverviewScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  final searchController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('Build');

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: searchController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search for a home',
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: ref.watch(searchProvider).isNotEmpty 
                  ? Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined)
                  : Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            print(value);
            // OR THE TEXT INSIDE THE SEARCH BAR
            ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).update((state) => state = value);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I would suggest to check `ConsumerStatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code to the following:

I needed to add the `ref.read().update` and `searchController.clear()` to clear the texted inside the textfield.

Or should I move the `Consumer` to a different place?

```dart
final searchProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');
final searchIsEmptyProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) => ref.watch(searchProvider).isEmpty);

class OverviewScreen extends ConsumerWidget {

  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // final houseDataValue = ref.watch(listHousesProvider);

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.75.h, bottom: 1.5.h, right: 4.2.w, left: 4.2.w),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.darkGray,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.w, top: 0.4.h),
              child: TextField(
                controller: searchController,
                cursorColor: AppColors.medium,
                style: AppTypography.input,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search for a home',
                  hintStyle: AppTypography.hint,
                  suffixIcon: Consumer(
                    builder: (context, ref, _) => ref.watch(searchIsEmptyProvider)
                        ? IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: AppColors.medium),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, color: AppColors.strong),
                            onPressed: () {
                              ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).update((_) => '');
                              searchController.clear();
                            },
                          ),
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  ref.read(searchProvider.notifier).update((_) => value);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListHouses(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, it got much better in the answer you provided. Add also a `dispose` in widget (use `ConsumerStatefulWidget`) method for the text controller